# NSolve with Bessel and Hankel functions

Tags: equation-solving, special-functions

I have a complicated function that I would like to solve for the roots. The function comprises Bessel and Hankel functions:

```
freq = 5*^9;
Omg = 2*Pi*freq;
rho = 15 ;
vco = 5907.5 (*core velocity*);
vcl = 5944 (*clad velocity*);
m = 0 ;
U = Sqrt[Omg^2/vco^2 - Omg^2/v];
W = Sqrt[Omg^2/vcl^2 - Omg^2/v];

NSolve[U*BesselJ[m + 1, U*rho]*HankelH1[m, W*rho] - W*HankelH1[m + 1, W*rho]*BesselJ[m, U*rho]==0, v]
```

However, NSolve does not evaluate. I have also tried using FindRoot but I have no idea what starting value to give. Plotting the function (with all variables equal to 1 for simplicity) is of no help for guessing starting values.

[image]

Comment: I'm getting the feeling that there are no roots.  Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

```
$Version

(* "12.1.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 19, 2020)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

freq = 5*^9;
Omg = 2*Pi*freq;
rho = 15;
vco = 5907.5 (*core velocity*);
vcl = 5944 (*clad velocity*);
m = 0;
U = Sqrt[Omg^2/vco^2 - Omg^2/v];
W = Sqrt[Omg^2/vcl^2 - Omg^2/v];
```

**EDIT 2:** Replacing `Rationalize` with `Rationalize[#, 0]&` to ensure conversion to rationals.

```
expr = U*BesselJ[m + 1, U*rho]*HankelH1[m, W*rho] - 
     W*HankelH1[m + 1, W*rho]*BesselJ[m, U*rho] // Rationalize[#, 0] & // 
   FullSimplify;

(sol = NSolve[{expr == 0, 10^7 < v < 10^8}, v, WorkingPrecision -> 50]) // N

(* {{v -> 3.533*10^7}} *)

expr /. sol // Quiet

(* {0.*10^-198964 + 0.*10^-198964 I} *)
```

In the definitions for `U` and `W` should the `v` be `v^2`? That provides a more reasonable value

```
Sqrt[v] /. sol // N

(* {5943.9} *)
```

**EDIT:** Using `v^2`

```
U = Sqrt[Omg^2/vco^2 - Omg^2/v^2];
W = Sqrt[Omg^2/vcl^2 - Omg^2/v^2];

expr = U*BesselJ[m + 1, U*rho]*HankelH1[m, W*rho] - 
     W*HankelH1[m + 1, W*rho]*BesselJ[m, U*rho] // 
    Rationalize[#, 0] & // FullSimplify;

(sol = NSolve[{expr == 0, 5000 < v < 6000}, v, 
    WorkingPrecision -> 50]) // N

(* {{v -> 5943.99}} *)
```

Comment: Yes it should be v^2. However, I thought introducing a square root would complicate things so I just called the whole thing v. Well, two of the solution are just the parameters vco and vcl. But there is a new third solution that I didn't have before. I don't see why // Rationalize // 
   FullSimplify would help here. It seems the real helper was the 10^7 < v < 10^8 you added.

Comment: And I tried with v^2 and it gives different solutions, so I think using v instead really helps the numerical solver

Comment: Also, how do you allow for complex solutions?

Comment: Already upvoted for the method, but I think it's a harder problem than `NSolve` can handle. Consider `Plot[RealExponent@expr, {v, 5800, 6000}, WorkingPrecision -> 100]`.  The gap in the graph is due to a singularity at ``expr /. v -> 5944``.